# How to send emails by using VB.NET or C# code from an office 365 account that multi factor authentication enabled on it?

Tags: c#, vb.net, office365, smtpclient, multi-factor-authentication

I have the following VB.NET code for sending emails from my office 365 account, it was worked fine until Microsoft forced to enable MFA on Office 365 accounts:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Sub main()

        Dim message As MailMessage = New MailMessage()
        message.From = New MailAddress("MyEmail@MyOffice365Account.com")
        message.To.Add(New MailAddress("Receiver@AnyEmail.com"))       
        message.Subject = "My subject"
        message.Body = "My body message"
        message.IsBodyHtml = True
        message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587)
        smtp.EnableSsl = True
        smtp.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("MyEmail@MyOffice365Email.com", "my password")
        smtp.Send(message)

End sub
```

When I run the above code I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException'
>   occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The SMTP server requires a secure connection
>   or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57
>   SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL
>   FROM [DB6PR0501CA0038.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com]

I'm sure the error is happened after I Enabled multi factor authentication on my account, and I cant disable this feature because Microsoft is forced Office 365 users to use this feature.

Is there is any way to solve this issue?

Comment: [Create an app password for Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-app-password-for-office-365-3e7c860f-bda4-4441-a618-b53953ee1183). As you can see in the Docs, the [SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient) class, Remarks section, is ~deprecated. The suggested substitute email client class is [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit).

Answer (score 0):

You can manually disable the MFA status of your 365 account. To do so, you need to setup your 365 Account Powershell.

Using powershell, disable MFA of the MSOL-User in your office 365 domain.

In your powershell, use this code to check all Msol-Users with MFA Status:

```
Get-MsolUser -all | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,@{N="MFA Status"; E={ if( $.StrongAuthenticationMethods.IsDefault -eq true) {(.StrongAuthenticationMethods | Where IsDefault -eq $True).MethodType} else { "Disabled"}}} | FT -AutoSize
```

Then to set the MFA Status to Disabled, use this code:

```
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName YourUserPrincipalNameHere -StrongAuthenticationRequirements @()
```